# How can I pull day of week in kotlin in android studio in datepiker no matter int or string

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-datepicker

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_randevu)
        binding = ActivityMainRandevuBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        var a = Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity_Ana_Sayfa::class.java)
        var b = Intent(applicationContext,MainActivity_Randevu_2::class.java)


        pickdate()


        binding.btngeri2.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(a)
        }



    }
    private fun getDateTimeCalendar (){
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        month= cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        dayofweek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    }
    private fun pickdate(){
        binding.btnBooking.setOnClickListener {
            getDateTimeCalendar()
            DatePickerDialog(this,this,year,month,day).show()



        }
    }
    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        savedDay = dayOfMonth
        savedYear = year
        savedMonth = month
    }

   
}
```

I can get day of month , month and year but ı can't get day of week. I have to get day of week because ı need to figure it out it is weekend or weekday.

Hello, i want to know if the date chosen is weekend in kotlin language. Can I get help with it?

I tried append some paramaters like day of week to OnDateSet but it is not working

Comment: What do you mean by you "cant get day of week"? Your code above looks like it would work, although it is rather convoluted that you have a function and a bunch of properties used to transfer individual values instead of just using the the values locally. Also, the Calendar class should be avoided when possible in favor of LocalDateTime, which is more robust and easier to use correctly.

Comment: I want to get chosen day of week. if you print dayofweek variable it is turning todays day I want to get chosen day example: if he chose 12 may 2023 i want to get day of week:friday month:may day of month:12 year:2023

Comment: Look at the LocalDate class. It will get you the day of week as an Enum instead of an integer. Just be careful about month, because it starts with January = 1, whereas DatePickerDialog starts with January = 0. So you have to add/subtract 1 to the month as appropriate.

Comment: I dont want todays day. I want chosen day from the date picker dialog